# Can I face a university programme?

Tags: expressions

Is the phrase "When I got admitted to the X University Department, I faced a truly interdisciplinary programme" correct?

Comment: `Is the phrase "When I got admitted to the X University Department, I faced a truly inderdisciplinary programme"?` - is it *what,* exactly. Not a good idea posting only sentence fragments on a site dedicated to EL&U :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While grammatically correct, you should consider what you're trying to suggest. Saying that you're "facing" the interdisciplinary program makes it sound like a particular challenge, or it may even be something that you are reluctant to do. A more neutral way to say it would be that you "experienced" the program, and a positive spin would be to say that you "enjoyed" the program.

Answer (score 1):

In this sense, *face* means to have to deal with something untoward:

> When I got admitted to the X University Department, I had **to face**
>   the fact that I wasn't prepared for a truly interdisciplinary
>   programme.

Or to have to confront a challenge:

> When I got admitted to the X University Department, I **faced** a truly
>   difficult challenge because the interdisciplinary programme
>   was conducted entirely in Swahili.

This metaphorical use of *face* has a slightly adversarial connotation, so it seems a little odd to use the word for a programme that you must have known about when you applied to the X Department and that the X Department must have felt you were prepared for (since they admitted you).  But if you were surprised or unprepared (a fact unknown from the missing context), it would be apt.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking if it's valid, so I would say yes.

You can "face" many things: a mirror, your adversary, an angry spouse because you've been out drinking with your mates, an uncertain future and, of course, a truly interdisciplinary programme.

---

The only thing I would *potentially* consider strange there would be `interdisciplinary` as in "between disciplines". I suspect `multidisciplinary` may be a better choice. However, as Matt points out in the comments, that's not necessarily so. In any case, it's an aside to the answer so feel free to ignore it.

Comment: In my experience (American English and universities), I have found interdisciplinary to be the more commonly used term. Google ngrams agrees with me, with multidisciplinary only showing up about half as much.

Comment: @Matt, well, `inter` is technically between, as in international relationships being between nations. Multi, on the other hand, means more than one, so a multinational company exists in more than one nation. An international company would be one domiciled somewhere in the middle of the ocean :-) In terms of a programme involved in several disciplines, I'd expect it to be across multiple disciplines, not restricted to only the interfaces between those disciplines. I could be wrong, it wouldn't be the first (or last) time.

Comment: I've found that the focus of interdisciplinary programs actually IS the interface between the disciplines. You could get a degree in Computer Science and one in Biology, but it's the interface between them that makes a good Computational Biology program. If the program was just multidisciplinary, why not just keep each individual program as a unit? It's the bridging of the gap that's often the important bit.

Comment: @Matt, good point, I'll degrade the importance of the statement in the answer, since it's not really core to it.